# How to get column name of an entrie's field

Tags: craft3, entries, field, query, entries-field

I want to query some entries in a section.

I am able to write a query using a GET Param as a filter on the title field.
If I want to query a custom field however I need to know the precise column otherwise craft yells at me.

How do I get to this information?

The following code is a very basic example of what I mean.

```
$request = Craft::$app->request;

$query = Entry::find()->section('profiles');
        
if($request->getParam('name')){
    $param = $request->getParam('name');
            
    $query->orWhere(['like', '`content`.`title`', $param]);
    $query->orWhere(['like', '`content`.`field_nationality_gkpaccfs`', $param]);
}

return $query->all();
```

Or is there a better alternative on how to query entries on multiple properties?
I know that $query->title(...) would work, but I do not know how to chain multiple of those together using OR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually [OK to hard code the complete field column name](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/6922#issuecomment-908871118) (i.e. `field_nationality_gkpaccfs`) – it won't change between environments, or if the field is resaved (unless you change the handle, of course).

If you don't want to do that, you can do this:

```php
use craft\helpers\ElementHelper;

$nationalityField = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldByHandle('nationality');
$nationalityFieldColumn = ElementHelper::fieldColumnFromField($nationalityField);

...
$query->orWhere(['like', '`content`.`' . $nationalityFieldColumn . '`', $param]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. It just seems wrong to write such a generated column name directly into the code, I much prefer using the ElementHelper Class.

Comment: Yeah I agree :)